# How can I parse a Date String with the format "\/Date(1339638938087-0500)\/" in Java?

Tags: java, json, datetime

I have String with the format `"\/Date(1339638938087-0500)\/"` from a web service api.

Using java, how can I put this into a `org.joda.time.DateTime` variable?

Comment: What does `\/Date(-2208967200000-0600)\/` represents  ?

Comment: It is supposed to represent a date and time.
I assumed that the first number was ms since Jan 1, 1970. But it is too big, it's some day in 2039. I will try to figure that out what it is. The second number is definitely a timezone.

Comment: @Adrian: It's not too big - it's *negative*... and the second number isn't a time zone, it's an offset. A time zone *gives* an offset at any point in time, but not the other way round. My current offset is +01:00, but it won't be in November... even though my time zone won't have changed.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up Jon, You were right it's negative and the data was bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract these two bits of information:

- -2208967200000: milliseconds since the unix epoch (January 1st 1970 UTC)
- -0600: offset from UTC

This assumes that the example represents January 1st 1900 at midnight local time - as the -2208967200000 part represents 6am UTC.

To convert this into a Joda Time `DateTime`, you should extract the two parts (get rid of everything outside the brackets, and then either use the length to split it, or find the middle +/- symbol).

Next, parse the first part as a `long` for the millis section.
Then, parse the second part - probably as hours, minutes and sign separately. (I'm assuming it's *always* in the form xHHmm where x is the sign, HH is the minutes as two digits, and mm is the hours as two digits.)

Create a fixed time zone for the offset using [`DateTimeZone.forHoursMinutesOffset`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forOffsetHoursMinutes%28int,%20int%29) or something similar.

Finally, create the time with

```
new DateTime(millis, zone);
```

Oh, and then kick whoever's producing such a horrible format...

Answer (score 0):

this look like unix timestamp

> The unix time stamp is a way to track time as a running total of
>   seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970

Comment: Doesn't look like a unix timestamp to me, unless you expect you think the OP is trying to represent about 68000BC. It looks very much like it's in *milliseconds* since the epoch - but also with an offset from UTC.

Comment: this is milliseconds, certainly, but with you start point i don't agree

Comment: What do you mean by "with you start point"? Which *precise* bit do you disagree with? If it's in milliseconds then it's *not* a Unix timestamp, and if you don't believe the "-0600" is an offset, what *do* you think it's for?

Comment: Sorry, it's still *really* unclear what you mean. I believe it's an offset in milliseconds since 1970, and I've never said anything else. I believe the *sample value* is January 1st 1900, because it's -70 years in milliseconds.

Comment: i decided that 1900 is not start point of counting, because what servise return so old date, it may return present or future, point of cointing must be more than 1900

Comment: But no-one ever suggested that 1900 was the epoch used here. I certainly didn't. I would utterly expect it to be 1970... which *with the large, negative sample value given in the question* would end up meaning 1900. Not 1900 as the baseline, but 1900 as the value. (And I can imagine plenty of reasons why a service might return a value representing 1900, actually...)

Answer (score 0):

If the "2208967200000" is a time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, you can use it in constructor for Date(time);

```
String dateStr="Date(-2208967200000-0600)";
String timeInMillis=dateStr.Split("-")[1];
String utcStr=dateStr.Split("-")[2].Substring(0,4);
Date d=new Date(Long.parseLong(timeInMillis));
```

if you want you can handle utcStr if it is necessary (if the second part after "-" is a time zone)

Comment: The number isn't 2208967200000 - it's -2208967200000, I believe. I see no other reason to put a - at the front, and it happens to end up being 06:00 on January 1st 1900 when viewed as negative, which seems too much of a coincidence (with the offset of -0600) to ignore.